# Detecting country names with nltk not working on forms

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

Im parsing a form which has this text

'1a. Country United States'

Which is not getting detected as GPE

```
from nltk import pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.tokenize import SpaceTokenizer

tokenizer = SpaceTokenizer()
toks = tokenizer.tokenize(cioms_)
pos = pos_tag(toks)
chunked_nes = ne_chunk(pos) 

nes = [' '.join(map(lambda x: x[0], ne.leaves())) for ne in chunked_nes if isinstance(ne, nltk.tree.Tree)]
chunked_nes

Out[83]: Tree('S', [(u'1a.', 'CD'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [(u'Country', 'NNP'), (u'United', 'NNP'), (u'States', 'NNPS')])])
```

But when I trim this to 'Country United States', its getting detected

```
Out[81]: Tree('S', [Tree('PERSON', [(u'Country', 'NNP')]), Tree('GPE', [(u'United', 'NNP'), (u'States', 'NNPS')])])
```

Why is it so ?

Comment: Has something to do with the `1a.` which it does not expect or causes issues. Why not use regex to remove unexpected items?, then classification would work properly.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy Im trying extract information from forms. While regex works for 1 type of such form, it wont work for the 4 other types which have "Place of residence" or "Citizenship" instead of "Country". I couldnt find anything which would cater to all such scenarios in such a generalized way. Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Looks like the default chunk parser is `NEChunkParser` which is a type of `NEChunkParserTagger` which uses a `nltk.classify.MaxentClassifier` classifier. This means the data is not representative of your data set. either re-train, preprocess the text, or use a different NE Chunker.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy how do I retrain "my data" on this (or any) parser ? Couldnt find anything relevant on this